# CodeIgniter Modules to Sub Domains

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, module, hmvc

I am developing the website in codeigniter with HMVC. I will have multiple subdomains which points to HMVC modules.
My current .htacess contains

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|themes|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

File structure

```
./application
    /modules
        /news_module
        /mobile_module
        /api_module
./system/
```

It works normal when typing

```
http://mysite.com/news_module/controller/method
http://mysite.com/mobile_module/controller/method
http://mysite.com/api_module/controller/method
```

But I want to redirect from

```
http://mysite.com/mobile_module/controller/method
```

to

```
http://m.mysite.com/mobile_module/controller/method
```

and hide (mobile_module) so finally

```
http://m.mysite.com/controller/method
```

In case sombody type

```
http://m.mysite.com/mobile_module/controller/method
```

also i want

```
http://m.mysite.com/controller/method
```

how can i do this in .htaccess?

Comment: if you want to redirect to m.mysite.com/.... first you have to create a subdomain

Comment: Hm, to me it seems like your actual question doesn't have anything to do with codeigniter or hmvc, just with how to write .htaccess file, right? if so, please tag correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the first part of your question use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^mobile_module/(.*) http://m.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Don't see how someone would just type m.mysite.com/mobile_module/***_*__*_*___**